# Terraform + DynamoDB - "All attributes must be indexed" error on terraform destroy

Tags: terraform, amazon-dynamodb

I am creating a TF configuration to setup DynamoDB with GSI. I am using .tfvars file to ingest my variables. I have added 3 keys in attributes (Partition and Sort) and GSI keys. when I run terraform apply -var-file = input.tfvars , it create DynamoDB just fine, I am able to see the table and GSI I have created. However when I try to destroy it, it gives me below error,

**Error: 1 error occurred:
│       * all attributes must be indexed. Unused attributes: ["title" "age"]**

Interestingly, if **I provide values directly in main.tf file not reading from .tfvars file**, it works fine and able destroy properly.

I have defined below variables ,

```
variable "attributes" {
  type            = list(map(string))
  description     = "(Required) Provide attributes for the table"
  default         = []
}

variable "global_secondary_indexes" {
  type            = any
  description     = " (Optional) Provide Global secondary indexes for a table"
  default         = []
}
```

and passing values in my .tfvars file as below, id (hash key), title (sort key), age (sort key for GSI)

```
attributes = [
  {
    name = "id"
    type = "N"
  },
  {
    name = "title"
    type = "S"
  },
  {
    name = "age"
    type = "N"
  }
]
global_secondary_indexes = [
  {
    name               = "TitleIndex"
    hash_key           = "title"
    range_key          = "age"
    projection_type    = "INCLUDE"
    read_capacity      = 5
    write_capacity     = 5
    non_key_attributes = ["id"]
  }
]
```

Reading values like below in main.tf

```
  attributes = var.attributes
  
  global_secondary_indexes = var.global_secondary_indexes
```

dynamoDB Module

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "this" {
  count = var.create_table && !var.autoscaling_enabled ? 1 : 0

  name             = var.name
  billing_mode     = var.billing_mode
  hash_key         = var.hash_key
  range_key        = var.range_key
  read_capacity    = var.read_capacity
  write_capacity   = var.write_capacity
  stream_enabled   = var.stream_enabled
  stream_view_type = var.stream_view_type

  ttl {
    enabled        = var.ttl_enabled
    attribute_name = var.ttl_attribute_name
  }

  point_in_time_recovery {
    enabled = var.point_in_time_recovery_enabled
  }

  dynamic "attribute" {
    for_each = var.attributes

    content {
      name = attribute.value.name
      type = attribute.value.type
    }
  }

  dynamic "global_secondary_index" {
    for_each = var.global_secondary_indexes

    content {
      name               = global_secondary_index.value.name
      hash_key           = global_secondary_index.value.hash_key
      projection_type    = global_secondary_index.value.projection_type
      range_key          = lookup(global_secondary_index.value, "range_key", null)
      read_capacity      = lookup(global_secondary_index.value, "read_capacity", null)
      write_capacity     = lookup(global_secondary_index.value, "write_capacity", null)
      non_key_attributes = lookup(global_secondary_index.value, "non_key_attributes", null)
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure why directly passing values to module is different than passing through a tfvars files.

Thanks

Comment: What is the code that generates the error?

Comment: Hi , I have updated dynamoDB module above.

Comment: What are var.hash_key and var.range_key?

Comment: These are below, hash_key                          = "id"
range_key                         = "title"